# How i can add click handler function to dynamically link in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Here in Vue component I receive dynamically message from server:

```
module.exports = {
  data() {
     return: { windowText: '' }
  },

  methods: {

    showCancelEntrieWindow(){
      this.$http.post('/page', {'number' : '123'})
          .then(response => {
               responseText = response.data.message;

               this.windowText = responseText.replace(
                  new RegExp("class='action'", 'g'), 
                  'v-on:click="myclick"'
               ); 

           });
    },
    myclick(){
       console.log('clicked!');
    }
  }
};
```

Message have a link with class="action".

As example:

```
  response.data.message = 'Some text... <a class="action" href="/test">test</a>';
```

In template:

```
<div v-html="windowText"></div>
```

How I can add some click handler function to this link?

I am trying to edit response.data.message  with replace function like this:

```
this.windowText = responseText.replace(
    new RegExp("class='action'", 'g'), 
    'v-on:click.stop="myclick"'
);
```

But it does not work.

Please help me.

And ofcourse, I can't edit response.data.message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`v-html` will not compile the template, so replacing the class with the Vue directive will not do anything.

You can, however, use a native event listener.

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data:{
    windowText: null,
    someValueSetOnClick: null
  },
  methods:{
    onHtmlClick(event){
      // Check to make sure this is from our v-html because
      // we don't want to handle clicks from other things in
      // the Vue
      if (!event.target.classList.contains("action"))
        return;

      event.stopPropagation();
      event.preventDefault();
      this.someValueSetOnClick = "Clicked";
    }
  },
  mounted(){
    this.windowText = 'Some text... <a class="action" href="/test">test</a>'

    // Add a native event listener to the Vue element.
    this.$el.addEventListener("click", this.onHtmlClick)
  }
})
```

[Example](http://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/VprJRK?editors=1010).

Comment: Thank you so much. It's really helpful. But i detected some negative effect. If link contains other element <a class="test"><b>test</b></a> or <a class="test"><img /></a> Then event applies to a nested element like b or img.

Comment: @AlexSemenov I updated the example pen to handle that case.